# Possible to do join queries in Android (for example to get contacts information)?

Tags: android, cursor

- Is it possible to make join queries and then iterate through the results ?
  How ? all in the same Cursor ?
- How to return the results of such a query ?
- For example, how should I proceed to get the name, phone number(s)
  and email(s) of a contact in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

Try CursorJoiner. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html